# Open kendo window in maximize mode as default

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to open kendo windows in maximize as default when click on button.
i have achieve using

```
$("#window").data("kendoWindow").maximize().open();
```

with actions: `[ "Maximize", "Close"]` and when i click on close button of kendo window and reopen the kendo window then it duplicates the restore button.

Comment: I tested this scenario in here and I didnt get this bug. I'm using Kendo 2016.1.112. What version do you use?

Comment: Please provide your code what you have tried.

Comment: @JValerio i am using same version of kendo i.e. 2016.1.112

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked 11 months ago but for those who came to this page looking for a solution, you simply need to open the window first and then maximize it.

```
$("#window").data("kendoWindow").open().maximize();
```

That simple!

I'm using UI for ASP.NET MVC, v.2016.2.714 and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this sample that is working here. Please try in this Kendo release.

```js
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
    actions: [ "Maximize",  "Close"],
    draggable: false,
    height: "300px",
    modal: true,
    pinned: false,
    position: {
        top: 100,
        left: 100
    },
    resizable: false,
    title: "Modal Window",
    width: "500px"
});
  
  
  $( "#target" ).click(function() {
   $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow").maximize().open();
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="dialog"></div>
  <div id="target">
  Click here
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am using same code but it is not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

var dialog= $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");

dialog.maximize();